# Create geometry shader using python opengl (PyOpenGL) failed

Tags: python, opengl, shader

I want to create geometry_shader using glCreateShader(GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER), but I get error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    geometry_shader = glCreateShader(GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER)
  File "errorchecker.pyx", line 53, in OpenGL_accelerate.errorchecker._ErrorChecker.glCheckError (src/errorchecker.c:1218)
OpenGL.error.GLError: GLError(
        err = 1280,
        description = b'invalid enumerant',
        baseOperation = glCreateShader,
        cArguments = (GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER,),
        result = 0
)
```

My environment:
Python version:3.6.7
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 18.0.5
OS version: ubuntu 18.04(ubuntu 16.04 tested same)
From [this site](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Geometry_Shader) I know that the minimum version is 3.2. So it should not be version issue.
Is it possible the bug of python wrapper of opengl?
Here is my test code.

```
import glfw
from OpenGL.GL import *
glfw.init()
glfw.window_hint(glfw.SAMPLES, 4)
window_size = (800, 600)
window = glfw.create_window(*window_size, 'Vehicle Model', None, None)
glfw.make_context_current(window)
vertice_shader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
geometry_shader = glCreateShader(GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER)
glfw.terminate()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify that the `GL_VERSION` string of your context is actually what you're assuming it is.

Mesa generally only gives you an OpenGL 2.1 context unless you specifically ask for a versioned Core context, though more drivers are getting Compatibility context support as time goes on.

With GLFW you generally request GL versions via [hints](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/window_guide.html#window_hints_values) set before window creation, in particular you'll want to set values for `GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR`, `GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR`, and `GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE`.