# Error with GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER creation using PyOpenGL

Tags: python, opengl, shader

I am trying to use PyOpenGL to create a geometry shader:

```
import glfw
from OpenGL.GL import *
glfw.init()
glfw.window_hint(glfw.SAMPLES, 4)
window_size = (800, 600)
window = glfw.create_window(*window_size, 'Vehicle Model', None, None)
glfw.make_context_current(window)
vertice_shader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
geometry_shader = glCreateShader(GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER)
glfw.terminate()
```

which is the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54939551/create-geometry-shader-using-python-opengl-pyopengl-failed). I also get the same error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GLError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-9df0fc607cbb> in <module>
      7 glfw.make_context_current(window)
      8 vertice_shader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
----> 9 geometry_shader = glCreateShader(GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER)
     10 glfw.terminate()

errorchecker.pyx in OpenGL_accelerate.errorchecker._ErrorChecker.glCheckError (src/errorchecker.c:1218)()

GLError: GLError(
        err = 1280,
        description = b'invalid enumerant',
        baseOperation = glCreateShader,
        cArguments = (GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER,),
        result = 0
)
```

I ask the question because I think I still have some problems with its answers. From [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54939551/create-geometry-shader-using-python-opengl-pyopengl-failed), it says that a matched version is required and a minimum version of 3.2 is need to `GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER`. However, the latest version of PyOpenGL is 3.1.

I use PyOpenGL 3.1 and my environment is:

```
>> glxinfo | grep -i opengl
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 6.0, 256 bits)
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 18.0.5
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 18.0.5
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 18.0.5
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

So my questions are:

1. How to get PyOpenGL with minimum version of 3.2 in order to use `GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER`.
2. Are there any specific code snippets to verify if the environment is matched?

Answer (score -1):

You don't need PyOpenGL 3.2 but an OpenGL context with version 3.2 and PyOpenGL supports context creation up to 4.4 according to their website.
You probably need to set something like:

```py
glfw.window_hint(glfw.CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3)
glfw.window_hint(glfw.CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2)
```

before window creation to set the context version.